# Python requests not returning fully loaded content

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to gain the sizes from [here](https://www.size.co.uk/product/grey-nike-air-max-98-se/132114/).

The content I want:

[image]

However I am receiving:

```html
[<div class="options" id="productSizeStock">
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
<button class="btn options-loading" disabled="" type="button">
</button>
```

I also tried using `requests-html` to see if it was a javascript rendering issue. But I was just receiving empty values.

Here is my code:

```py
import requests
import randomheaders
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

proxy = {'''PROXY'''}
while True:
    try:
        source = requests.get("https://www.size.co.uk/product/grey-nike-air-max-98-se/132114/", proxies= proxy, headers=randomheaders.LoadHeader(),timeout=30).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features = "lxml")
        print(soup.find_all("div", class_="options"))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from a technical point of view your code is correct. As this website uses Javascript  to render itself, the size is store on a different URL, which is the following:

```
https://www.size.co.uk/product/grey-nike-air-max-98-se/132114/stock
```

as you can see you just have to add */stock* to your initial URL.

---

That being said, try replacing this:

```
source = requests.get("https://www.size.co.uk/product/grey-nike-air-max-98-se/132114/", proxies= proxy, headers=randomheaders.LoadHeader(),timeout=30).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features = "lxml")
print(soup.find_all("div", class_="options"))
```

with:

```
source = requests.get("https://www.size.co.uk/product/grey-nike-air-max-98-se/132114/stock", proxies= proxy, headers=randomheaders.LoadHeader(),timeout=30).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features = "lxml")
sizes = [x["title"].replace("Select Your UK Size ","") for x in soup.find_all("button",{"data-e2e":"product-size"})]
print(sizes)
```

Where `sizes` is a list containing all of the sizes and has the following output:

```
['6', '7', '7.5', '8', '8.5', '9', '9.5', '10', '10.5', '11', '11.5', '12']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for responding! Were you able to hit the service? I keep having connection timed out problem :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691190/requests-html-httpsconnectionpoolread-timed-out

Comment: @kyraaan hmm I'm pretty sure its an issue with your proxy in this case. have you checked them out?

Comment: I think you are right! From switching proxies I have now managed to get a response every so often. It is very inconsistent though, even with 1000000 timeout

Comment: Try to send a request without using a proxy and tell me if it works or not

Comment: Disabled proxy, increased timeout even more now and im getting more frequent responses. Thank you so much for your help! I guess the site is just very slow haha

Answer (score 3):

It is probably because the information you are searching for is added dynamically by a client-side script (JS in this case). I don't see an easy way to get the information simply with `requests` if it's the case, probably you should analyse better the page scripting and if really motivated perform the proper `AJAX` requests.

So, to recap, you are not getting the correct results because any JS generated content has to be rendered on the document. When you fetch the HTML page, you fetch only the initial document.

A possible solution (the solution is for **Python's 3.6** only) consists at using [requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) instead of [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

> This library intends to make parsing HTML (e.g. scraping the web) as simple and intuitive as possible.

1. Install requests-html: `pipenv install requests-html`
2. Make a request to the page's url:

   ```
   from requests_html import HTMLSession

   session = HTMLSession()
   r = session.get(a_page_url)
   ```
3. Render the response to get the Javascript generated bits:

   ```
   r.html.render()
   ```

This module offers [scraping](https://html.python-requests.org/#api-documentation) and JavaScript Support, that is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks @AlexGidan for replying! I had a feeling it was with that, thank you for clearning that up.
When requests-html, I mentioned above that upon trying it, I was being returned none? Here was the code

`r = session.get("https://www.size.co.uk/product/grey-nike-air-max-98-se/132114/",proxies = proxy)
print(r.html.render(timeout=20))`