# requests-html HTTPSConnectionPoolRead timed out

Tags: session, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

Trying to send a request to [here](https://www.size.co.uk/product/white-fila-v94m-low/119095/)
using `requests-html`.

Here is my code:

```py
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"}
session = HTMLSession()
while True:
   try:
       r = session.get("https://www.size.co.uk/product/white-fila-v94m-low/119095/",headers=headers,timeout=40)
       r.html.render()
       print(r.html.text)

   except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.size.co.uk', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=40)
```

I thought setting the user agent would fix the problem, but I am still receiving the error? Increasing the timeout hasn't done the trick either

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. `Read timed out. (read timeout=40)` Increase the `timeout`. It is a super slow website and needs longer to load.

Comment: @antfuentes87 thanks for your response! I will increase timeout and report back :)

Comment: Setting timeout to `100000` is still giving read timeout error

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Async

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

s = AsyncHTMLSession()
async def main():
    r = await s.get('https://www.size.co.uk/product/white-fila-v94m-low/119095/')
    await r.html.arender()
    print(r.content)

s.run(main)
```